# ngroute does not display any outcome

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am learning and experimenting with multiple views and routing. For this reason, I have written three files test.html, controllers.js, and app.js. When I run the application, ideally the view1 should display the message and view2 should display date time. But it is just displaying two tabs as view 1 and view 2 and the message and dates are not being displayed. I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

My test.html

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
 <head>  
 <meta charset="utf-8">  
 <title>AngularJS Routing</title>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/> 
 </head> 
 <body>

  <ul class="menu"> 
  <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>  
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script> 
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

my app.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp',['myApp.controllers','ngRoute']);
angular.module('myApp').config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/view1',{
        controller: 'Controller1',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html'
    }).when('/view2',{
        controller: 'Controller2',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html'
    });
});
```

my controllers.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]).
controller('Controller1',function($scope){
    $scope.message="Hello, world";
}).controller('Controller2',function($scope){
    $scope.now=new Date();
});
```

Kindly let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your controller.js ahead of app.js since the module **myApp** is dependent on the **`myApp.controllers`**

```
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hn1jbE0ozDdRJXjFvMj3?p=preview)**

Comment: No I do not see any error. No I have not downvoted. It is still showing 0

Comment: @bhaskardas check the demo added